# Feignebaum delta computation using Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-analysis

I am new to Matlab and currently trying to pass an online course on it. The task is to compute Feigenbauim's constant, delta, which  is the limiting ratio of each bifurcation interval to the next between every period doubling, of a one-parameter logistic map, to an arbitrary degree of accuracy. Here is my script:

```
% Compute the Feigenbaum delta
% Store approximate values in the row vector delta for assessment, where length(delta)= num_doublings and 
% delta(2:num_doublings) are computed from the algorithm described in Lectures 21-23.
num_doublings=11; delta=zeros(1,num_doublings); delta(1)=5;
% Write your code here

m(1)=2;
m(2)=1+sqrt(5);


for i=2:num_doublings
    x0 = 1/2; 
    dx0 = 0;
    period =2^(i-1);
    m(i+1)=m(i)+(m(i)-m(i-1))/delta(i-1);
   
    for j=1:100
        for k=1:period
            x = m(i+1)*x0*(1-x0);
            x_p = x0*(1-x0) + m(i+1)*dx0*(1-2*x0);
            
            x0 = x; dx0 = x_p;
        end
        u(j)= m(i+1)-(x0-0.5)/dx0;
    end
    m(i+1)=u(j);
    delta(i)=(m(i)-m(i-1))/(m(i+1)-m(i));
end

% Output your results
fprintf('n        delta(n)\n');
for n=1:num_doublings
    fprintf('%2g %18.15f\n',n,delta(n));
end
```

It computes the constant only to the fifth decimal place, and don't know, why if anyone would be willing to give any advice on how to improve it, it would be appreaciated

Comment: Well the degree of accuracy is limited to numerical precision... Can you clarify what you mean by '(i)t computes the constant only to the fifth decimal place'? When I run your code it prints `delta(n)` to 15 decimal places as it should.

Comment: As @dmedine mentioned, this MATLAB does compute all your decimals and this is purely a display issue from the standard `format short`, which limits to 5 decimal places. Your `fprintf()` statement already allows for 18 pre-decimal and 15 post-decimal places (which seems to be overkill). See the linked duplicate on formatting your numbers for display purposes. Ping me if that's not your issue, in which case you should also [edit] the question to show why the duplicate does not solve your problem.